# User namespaces: how to mount a folder only for a given program

Tags: mount, userns

I'd like to fake a FHS system on a non-FHS system (NixOs) without root access. To that end, I need to mount some folders at the root (like mounting `/tmp/mylib` to `/lib`) using usernamespaces (I don't see any other solution).

Unfortunately, I can't find how to make it work: I tried to follow [this tutorial](https://lwn.net/Articles/532593/), but when I copy the code it fail (I can't even start a bash):

```
$ gcc userns_child_exec.c -lcap -o userns_child_exec
$ id
uid=1000(myname) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),1(wheel),17(audio),20(lp),57(networkmanager),59(scanner),131(docker),998(vboxusers),999(adbusers)

$ ./userns_child_exec -U -M '0 1000 1' -G '0 100 1' bash
write /proc/535313/gid_map: Operation not permitted
bash: initialize_job_control: no job control in background: Bad file descriptor

[nix-shell:~/Documents/Logiciels/Nix_bidouille/2022_04_26_-_nix_fake_FHS_user_namespace/demo]$ 
[root@bestos:~/Documents/Logiciels/Nix_bidouille/2022_04_26_-_nix_fake_FHS_user_namespace/demo]# 
exit
```

(note that the prompt for the bash is displayed, but then I can't type anything, it quits directly)

Any idea how to make it work?

Code:

```
/* userns_child_exec.c

   Copyright 2013, Michael Kerrisk
   Licensed under GNU General Public License v2 or later

   Create a child process that executes a shell command in new
   namespace(s); allow UID and GID mappings to be specified when
   creating a user namespace.
*/
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <errno.h>

/* A simple error-handling function: print an error message based
   on the value in 'errno' and terminate the calling process */

#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                        } while (0)

struct child_args {
    char **argv;        /* Command to be executed by child, with arguments */
    int    pipe_fd[2];  /* Pipe used to synchronize parent and child */
};

static int verbose;

static void
usage(char *pname)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s [options] cmd [arg...]\n\n", pname);
    fprintf(stderr, "Create a child process that executes a shell command "
            "in a new user namespace,\n"
            "and possibly also other new namespace(s).\n\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "Options can be:\n\n");
#define fpe(str) fprintf(stderr, "    %s", str);
    fpe("-i          New IPC namespace\n");
    fpe("-m          New mount namespace\n");
    fpe("-n          New network namespace\n");
    fpe("-p          New PID namespace\n");
    fpe("-u          New UTS namespace\n");
    fpe("-U          New user namespace\n");
    fpe("-M uid_map  Specify UID map for user namespace\n");
    fpe("-G gid_map  Specify GID map for user namespace\n");
    fpe("            If -M or -G is specified, -U is required\n");
    fpe("-v          Display verbose messages\n");
    fpe("\n");
    fpe("Map strings for -M and -G consist of records of the form:\n");
    fpe("\n");
    fpe("    ID-inside-ns   ID-outside-ns   len\n");
    fpe("\n");
    fpe("A map string can contain multiple records, separated by commas;\n");
    fpe("the commas are replaced by newlines before writing to map files.\n");

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* Update the mapping file 'map_file', with the value provided in
   'mapping', a string that defines a UID or GID mapping. A UID or
   GID mapping consists of one or more newline-delimited records
   of the form:

       ID_inside-ns    ID-outside-ns   length

   Requiring the user to supply a string that contains newlines is
   of course inconvenient for command-line use. Thus, we permit the
   use of commas to delimit records in this string, and replace them
   with newlines before writing the string to the file. */

static void
update_map(char *mapping, char *map_file)
{
    int fd, j;
    size_t map_len;     /* Length of 'mapping' */

    /* Replace commas in mapping string with newlines */

    map_len = strlen(mapping);
    for (j = 0; j < map_len; j++)
        if (mapping[j] == ',')
            mapping[j] = '\n';

    fd = open(map_file, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "open %s: %s\n", map_file, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (write(fd, mapping, map_len) != map_len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "write %s: %s\n", map_file, strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    close(fd);
}

static int              /* Start function for cloned child */
childFunc(void *arg)
{
    struct child_args *args = (struct child_args *) arg;
    char ch;

    /* Wait until the parent has updated the UID and GID mappings. See
       the comment in main(). We wait for end of file on a pipe that will
       be closed by the parent process once it has updated the mappings. */

    close(args->pipe_fd[1]);    /* Close our descriptor for the write end
                                   of the pipe so that we see EOF when
                                   parent closes its descriptor */
    if (read(args->pipe_fd[0], &ch, 1) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failure in child: read from pipe returned != 0\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /* Execute a shell command */

    execvp(args->argv[0], args->argv);
    errExit("execvp");
}

#define STACK_SIZE (1024 * 1024)

static char child_stack[STACK_SIZE];    /* Space for child's stack */

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int flags, opt;
    pid_t child_pid;
    struct child_args args;
    char *uid_map, *gid_map;
    char map_path[PATH_MAX];

    /* Parse command-line options. The initial '+' character in
       the final getopt() argument prevents GNU-style permutation
       of command-line options. That's useful, since sometimes
       the 'command' to be executed by this program itself
       has command-line options. We don't want getopt() to treat
       those as options to this program. */

    flags = 0;
    verbose = 0;
    gid_map = NULL;
    uid_map = NULL;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "+imnpuUM:G:v")) != -1) {
        switch (opt) {
        case 'i': flags |= CLONE_NEWIPC;        break;
        case 'm': flags |= CLONE_NEWNS;         break;
        case 'n': flags |= CLONE_NEWNET;        break;
        case 'p': flags |= CLONE_NEWPID;        break;
        case 'u': flags |= CLONE_NEWUTS;        break;
        case 'v': verbose = 1;                  break;
        case 'M': uid_map = optarg;             break;
        case 'G': gid_map = optarg;             break;
        case 'U': flags |= CLONE_NEWUSER;       break;
        default:  usage(argv[0]);
        }
    }

    /* -M or -G without -U is nonsensical */

    if ((uid_map != NULL || gid_map != NULL) &&
            !(flags & CLONE_NEWUSER))
        usage(argv[0]);

    args.argv = &argv[optind];

    /* We use a pipe to synchronize the parent and child, in order to
       ensure that the parent sets the UID and GID maps before the child
       calls execve(). This ensures that the child maintains its
       capabilities during the execve() in the common case where we
       want to map the child's effective user ID to 0 in the new user
       namespace. Without this synchronization, the child would lose
       its capabilities if it performed an execve() with nonzero
       user IDs (see the capabilities(7) man page for details of the
       transformation of a process's capabilities during execve()). */

    if (pipe(args.pipe_fd) == -1)
        errExit("pipe");

    /* Create the child in new namespace(s) */

    child_pid = clone(childFunc, child_stack + STACK_SIZE,
                      flags | SIGCHLD, &args);
    if (child_pid == -1)
        errExit("clone");

    /* Parent falls through to here */

    if (verbose)
        printf("%s: PID of child created by clone() is %ld\n",
                argv[0], (long) child_pid);

    /* Update the UID and GID maps in the child */

    if (uid_map != NULL) {
        snprintf(map_path, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%ld/uid_map",
                (long) child_pid);
        update_map(uid_map, map_path);
    }
    if (gid_map != NULL) {
        snprintf(map_path, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%ld/gid_map",
                (long) child_pid);
        update_map(gid_map, map_path);
    }

    /* Close the write end of the pipe, to signal to the child that we
       have updated the UID and GID maps */

    close(args.pipe_fd[1]);

    if (waitpid(child_pid, NULL, 0) == -1)      /* Wait for child */
        errExit("waitpid");

    if (verbose)
        printf("%s: terminating\n", argv[0]);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**EDIT**

Actually, it's quite weird: the error appears when writing the group, but it did work for the uid:

```
[leo@bestos:~]$ cat /proc/582197/gid_map 

[leo@bestos:~]$ cat /proc/582197/uid_map 
         0       1000          1

[leo@bestos:~]$ ll /proc/582197/gid_map 
-rw-r--r-- 1 leo users 0 mai   18 09:09 /proc/582197/gid_map

[leo@bestos:~]$ ll /proc/582197/uid_map 
-rw-r--r-- 1 leo users 0 mai   18 09:09 /proc/582197/uid_map
```

Comment: My comment was wrong but I figured out the actual issue. Answer in progress.

Comment: I hope you noticed I gave an answer and an explanation heh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you're reading was created in 2013 before an important additional restriction was added to handling *GID* mappings in kernel 3.19 in 2015. As per [`man user_namespaces`](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/user_namespaces.7#Interaction_with_system_calls_that_change_process_UIDs_or_GIDs):

> **Writing "deny"** to the */proc/[pid]/setgroups* file before writing to
> */proc/[pid]/gid_map* **will** permanently disable setgroups(2) in a user
> namespace and **allow writing to /proc/[pid]/gid_map without having the
> CAP_SETGID capability in the parent user namespace.**

> The ***/proc/[pid]/setgroups* file was added in Linux 3.19**, but was
> backported to many earlier stable kernel series, because it addresses
> a security issue. The issue concerned files with permissions such as
> "rwx---rwx". Such files give fewer permissions to "group" than they do
> to "other". This means that dropping groups using setgroups(2) might
> allow a process file access that it did not formerly have. Before the
> existence of user namespaces this was not a concern [...] This then allowed formerly
> unprivileged users to drop groups and thus gain file access that they
> did not previously have. [...]

So you must add code to write the word `deny` to the file whose name is `snprintf(map_path, PATH_MAX, "/proc/%ld/setgroups", (long) child_pid);` right before writing to `gid_map`.

The whole code can be replaced with this ubiquitous command:

```
unshare --user --map-root-user --mount -- bash
```

(which has an implicit `--setgroups=deny`)

Also without privileges only ONE uid/gid can be mapped. So once mounts are done the only possible choice to simulate the original user, albeit incompletely is to map back to the original user, which can be done with a recent version of `unshare` too with a 2nd cascaded user namespace from the one just unshared:

```
# unshare --user --map-user=1000 --map-group=100 -- bash
```

then there will be ONE uid in this namespace. even root doesn't exist anymore (and is seen mapped as `nobody` as any other unmapped uid).

---

Note

There are other interactions with other namespaces and capabilities, [here's an example](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/user_namespaces.7.en.html#Effect_of_capabilities_within_a_user_namespace):

> Holding `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` within the user namespace that owns a process's
> PID namespace allows (since Linux 3.8) that process to mount */proc*
> filesystems.

So adding `--pid --fork` to comply with the restriction above allows to mount `/proc` over the existing one if this was ever needed later, but usually this is needed only when using `--pid` in the first place (and this can also conveniently be done by adding `--mount-proc`).

Likewise `--net` is required to mount `/sys` because of its interactions with network namespaces.

---

Putting all this together to replace `/lib` by the content of `/tmp/o` as [OP's example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702980/user-namespaces-how-to-mount-a-folder-only-for-a-given-program/702985?noredirect=1#comment1330253_702985):

```bsh
unshare --user --map-root-user --mount -- \
    sh -c 'mount --bind /tmp/o /lib; exec unshare --user --map-user=1000 --map-group=100 -- bash'
```

Note: It's not possible to use most privileged commands properly anymore once having done the first mapping: either there's the single UID 0 available in the user namespace, or there's the single UID 1000 available in the next (nested) user namespace. As privileged commands handle transition between two UIDs (one of them usually root) and one is not available it will usually fail at some syscall with EINVAL.

To do better than this, one needs assistance from privileged commands in the first place, and root access to configure additional rights. For example the setuid root commands `newuidmap` and `newgidmap` which are usually needed to bootstrap a complete container from an user without privilege.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! (sorry for the delay, I could not test it before today) So it works great (+1), thanks a lot for explaining and providing the great unshare command equivalent. Now, I'm not sure how to go further to completely answer my initial answer (which is, basically, to fake a folder that does not exist, like `/lib` in NixOs). Am I just supposed to do `mount --bind /tmp/o /lib` once I'm in the `unshare --user --map-root-user --mount -- bash`?When I do so I get bitten by this bug https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/42117 but I'm not sure if this is the proper way to proceed

Comment: I can't tell about NixOS, but my answer didn't use sudo because I expect sudo won't work because root isn't mapped anymore. If you want to do all this one-shot, you can chain this using sh and exec to limit intermediate processes etc: `unshare --user --map-root-user --mount -- sh -c 'mount --bind /tmp/o /lib; exec unshare --user --map-user=1000 --map-group=100 -- bash'`.

Comment: Whatever you do it can't be used to circumvent security or gain privileges: that would be a bug if it could succeed.

Comment: Added an example based on your comment in the answer.

Comment: Actually, when specifying the full path of mount (without the wrapper) I can go a step further: `/run/current-system/sw/bin/mount --bind /tmp/o /lib`. Unfortunately, this fails with `mount: /lib: mount point does not exist.` This is quite expected as /lib does not exists, but I can't create this file without root access. Is there a solution avoiding this issue?

Comment: Sorry but you're adding further details to the question (or rather not even to the question but in comments) at each step which fails and I won't continue updating my answer. Look at the initial problem in the question: it was about setgroups=deny. Suggestion: create a new directory, mkdir at will and bind everything else in this new directory then chroot to it (before the 2nd unshare).

Comment: Otherwise, thanks a lot for the example, it works greatly if the folder exists (but sadly I can't find how to avoid the need of creating this file). I'll accept the answer, but I'd love to know if you have a way to solve this problem as well. Also, it's too bad I can't use `sudo` anymore… I'll try to see if I can understand how `newuidmap` works, otherwise I'll create a new question.

Comment: Ahah, sorry for the confusion but I wrote the comments before seing your answer (I got no notifications saying a new comment were posted, so I was just documenting my progress). Anyway, you perfectly answered my question, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Just to complete the great answer of A.B. and to make a comment written by A.B. more visible, if the folder is supposed to be mounted in a folder that does not yet exists, it's possible to use chroot inside the `unshare`:

```
$ unshare --user --map-root-user --mount-proc --pid --fork
# cd /tmp/ && mkdir mychroot && cd mychroot
# for folder in $(ls / | grep -v sys); do echo "$folder"; mkdir "./$folder"; mount --rbind "/$folder" "./$folder"; done; mkdir sys; mount --rbind /sys sys/
# mkdir lib
# chroot .
# ls /
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  mnt  nix  opt  proc  root  run  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
```

Note that here you can't use sudo, everything you will do will be as a normal user. I'll try to see if `newuidmap` can help here.

(NB NixOs users may need to use `/run/current-system/sw/bin/mount` instead of `mount` https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/issues/42117)