# How to mount folders on a per-process basis while keeping all functionalities of regular shell

Tags: mount, namespace

In order to fake a FHS OS on a non-FHS OS (NixOs) and to increase "purity", I need to mount some folders and overlay other folders in a per-process basis, for instance `/lib` does not exists in NixOs and I'd like to provide such folders for some applications  (I don't want to mount it globally). Similarly, I want to overlay the `/bin` folder: it only contains `/bin/sh` and I'd like to link other executables, say `/bin/bash`.

Ideally, I'd like to have a command that mounts/overlays the appropriate folders and that drops me in a shell having the same functionalities as a normal shell. In particular **I should be able to run sudo or normal commands, run fusermount commands** (in particular to run appimages), access to the network…

Ideally, this command should be **executed as a non-root user**. If possible, I'd love to make it work without any suid binary using namespaces, but if I don't have any choice I'm fine to rely on setuid (if it does not break the security of the rest of the system), or, if no other choices are possible, on sudo.

I tried to use user namespaces + mount namespace + chroot, unfortunately here I can't run sudo applications as the namespace hides the root account (cf. [User namespaces: how to mount a folder only for a given program](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702980/user-namespaces-how-to-mount-a-folder-only-for-a-given-program/702985)). Other tools like bubblewrap can't run fusermount commands. Is there another solution?

Comment: How do you expect to solve mounting conflicts?

Comment: @WhiteOwl? What do you mean? For overlays you mean? Well I heard that there exists some tools that can specify multiples folders to mount, and it's possible to specify priorities between folders. Like  fuse-overlayfs and I think that the kernel also gave similar tools see https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/podman-rootless-overlay

Comment: If AppA wants to have `/lib` pointing at one device and AppB wants the same `/lib` to point to another device? Device mounting is a system-wide thing...

Comment: @WhiteOwl Well with recent kernel features (user & mount namespaces) or chroot-like features, one can mount stuff on a per-process basis. And it works, up to some extend (can't use root anymore) as I explained above.